# ¿Cómo se dice "Christmas caroling" en español?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

Creo que la palabra mejor para "Christmas carol" es *villancicos*, pero ¿hay una forma como verbo?

Por ejemplo, en inglés se puede decir:

> We are going Christmas Caroling tonight at 8.

Pero en español se debería decir:

> Vamos a caminar desde casa a casa y cantar villancicos esta noche a las 8.

Cierto, pero habrá alguna manera una más concisa, ¿verdad?

Answer (score 8):

No se diría "desde casa a casas" sino "de casa en casa". Así mismo sería más correcto decir "Iremos" en vez de "Vamos a ir".

En cuanto a lo que se refiere propiamente a la expresión "Christmas caroling", debo decir que, si bien no me consta tal tradición (de forma generalizada) en España, sí existe la que dice @Amedio de "pedir el aguinaldo" asociada a "cantar villancicos".

Por tanto, si le vas a explicar a un hispanohablante que simplemente vas a ir cantando villancicos de puerta en puerta, diría que la traducción correcta sería:

> A las 8 de la tarde, iremos de puerta en puerta cantando villancicos.

Happy Xmas Caroling!

Comment: Mil veces mejor explicado que yo :D gracias

Answer (score 1):

En España, solemos decir que vamos a "pedir el aguinaldo".

Que yo sepa no hay ningún verbo como con Christmas Caroling sucede en inglés.

El hecho que se diga "pedir el aguinaldo" es porque se canta el siguiente villancico:

> Dame el aguinaldo,carita de rosa...
>   que no tienes cara de ser tan roñosa...
>   Y si me lo das,o no me lo das...
>   Gracias igualmente y feliz navidad...

Es un villancico en el que, directamente, se pide el [aguinaldo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aguinaldo).

**EDITO:**

Al menos yo, en España, no conozco otra tradición de la de pedir el aguinaldo, no solo se canta ese villancico que he puesto arriba sino que se cantan más, se va puerta por puerta recitando diferentes villancicos.

Por eso mismo al autor de la pregunta le recomiendo, que primero se espere a que haya algún usuario más que pueda dar una mejor explicación para su respuesta, ya que quizá pedir el aguinaldo, puede ser que no se adecue en el caso de otros países latinos.

Comment: Por pedir el aguinaldo se entiende el pedir una pequeña cantidad de dinero (óbolo) y lo que se ofrece a cambio es un villancico. El hecho de ir cantando de puerta en puerta sería eso: A las 8 de la tarde, iremos de puerta en puerta cantando villancicos.

Comment: Yo simplemente lo decía porque en España nunca se ha ido puerta por puerta cantando villancicos, y siempre se ha tenido la tradición de pedir el aguinaldo, una acción en la que se cantan villancicos, no solo el de pedida del aguinaldo.

Comment: También yo soy de España y diría que excepto en pueblos, se ha perdido la tradición del aguinaldo. Si bien concuerdo contigo y no me consta en que haya habido una tradición de cantar villancicos sin pedir el aguinaldo a cambio.

Comment: Yo soy de ciudad, y ahora se vuelve a la tradición del aguinaldo, este año ya han venido 2 grupos de chavales. Y he de confesar que yo lo hice una vez también.

Comment: El en el País Vasco y Navarra, en las zonas de influencia vasca, debido al Olentzero es algo que se ha hecho siempre, aunque en los últimos 5 años creo que se ha perdido, hoy de hecho no ha venido nadie a cantar.